# Coral USB accelerator with OpenCV

Tags: google-coral, raspberry-pi4

i am curious if someone has implemented Yolo or SSD // OpenCV on RPi 4 with Coral Usb Accelerator support.

Currently, i faced some issue running even for the basic examples for coral usb accelerator. Do you have any tips in tackling this idea?

Moreover, i would like to use this setup to detect the road signs from a car's camera. Do you think it would be ok?

Answer (score 0):

What type of issues are you having while running the basic demo?
Also, make sure your model meets the requirements for the tpu:
https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#compatibility-overview